# Update UITableViewCells after GET request

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to update an unread badge in my `UITableViewCell`s. Therefore, I created this method:

```
- (void)unreadCounts:(NSArray *)resultarray {
    NSInteger count = [self.resultArray count];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];

    [database open];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSString *id = [[self.resultArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];

        NSString *stringURL = @"http://example.com";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];

        NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *accessToken = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"AccessToken"];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request addValue:accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        [request addValue:id forHTTPHeaderField:@"ID"];

        //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

        if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
        {
            NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                   error:&error];

           NSInteger *unread = [json objectForKey:@"unread"];

          NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update unread set unread='%d' where id='%@'", unread, id];
          [database executeUpdate:query];
        }
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And this function is called in `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
[self unreadCounts:self.resultArray];
```

What happens now is that when the view opens, this code is being ran first. What I, ideally, want though is for the view to load and after this function has finished running, it updates the `UITableViewCell`s. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `-sendSynchronousRequest:` is bad news bears. Definitely want that to be on a background thread so it doesn't block the UI. Use the async method instead .... also I would re-think your approach to calling this method on the UI thread at all. Seems to me you want your view controller to load and display, then update automatically when these HTTP calls finish. Check out Grand Central Dispatch for that.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks a bunch. It doesn't work with `-sendSynchronousRequest:`, but I'll rewrite this with Grand Central Dispatch. Let's hope for the best.

Comment: Remember to always update the UI from the main thread. There are lots of examples of how to do this using a background thread in GCD.